# Is it possible to deny minify one line (or region) in css file by Microsoft Ajax Minifier?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, css, microsoft-ajax-minifier, cassette

I started use [Cassette](http://getcassette.net) library in our project. This library use Microsoft Ajax Minifier by default. I face problems breaking html layout on some pages only in firefox browser. I found that problem is related to CSS3 function calc(). The + and - operators must always be [surrounded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) by whitespace in this function. I can redefine this properties somewhere out of this minify area but I don`t want to do that. I want to fix it inside file. Is it possible?

Comment: Please show the exact code example you're trying to fix and show what causes the problem after minimization.

Comment: before: `width: calc(24.3% - 30px);`, after: `width:calc(24.3%-30px);` Is it clear?

Comment: Thanks for this question ... I just pulled my hair out because I didn't understand why I Firefox lost the calc() parts in the stylesheets while it worked fine in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that using `-moz-` prefix for `calc` function leaves it untouched after minifier.
Example:

```
.some_class {
  width: calc(24.3% - 30px);
  width: -webkit-calc(24.3% - 30px);
  width: -moz-calc(24.3% - 30px);
}
```

Becomes:

```
.some_class{width:calc(24.3%- 30px);width:-webkit-calc(24.3% - 30px);width:-moz-calc(24.3% - 30px)}
```

Comment: Works starting with IE9